# iOS: NSURLConnection makes other TCP connections not possible

Tags: ios, networking, nsurlconnection

I have an app that repeatedly calls NSDictionary's dictionaryWithContentsOfURL then NSURLConnection to download a file.  It does this a handful of times then dictionaryWithContentsOfURL eventually will stop sending out HTTP requests and will time-out and return nil.  It usually only takes 6 cycles before this happens.

extra info:

- I was using ASIHTTPRequest before, but ended up writing everything with dictionaryWithContentsOfURL and NSURLConnection and I get the same results.
- I've use a packet sniffer and saw that dictionaryWithContentsOfURL is not issuing a HTTP request like it did previously.
- If I run the app and only call dictionaryWithContentsOfURL and don't create NSURLConnection's it doesn't get in this goofy state.
- Restarting the app makes dictionaryWithContentsOfURL start working again but will promptly return to its goofy state.
- I've put a breakpoint on -[NSURLConnection dealloc] and it is called.

I'm guessing the OS is not allowing me to open new sockets or something, any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?  Thanks.